# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Texture Atlas Not Found'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created a project that has a simple animation using Sprite Kit. It worked well and there is no problem in it.
The error occurs when I merged the files in our working copy.

```
NSMutableArray *dPFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

SKTextureAtlas *dPAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"dP"]; <<---- Thread 1: signal SIGBART

int numImages = dPAtlas.textureNames.count;

for (int i=1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dP%d@2x", i];
    SKTexture *temp = [dPAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
    [dPFrames addObject:temp];

}
_dPAnimateFrames = dPFrames;

SKTexture *temp = _dPAnimateFrames[0];
_dP = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];
_dP.position = CGPointMake(150, 110);
[self addChild:_dP];
```

Here is the message in Console:

> 2013-10-09 10:52:14.777 MyProject[1550:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Texture Atlas Not Found', reason: 'Texture Atlas Not Found'

I have search and research for answer but unfortunately I found nothing. Please share solution if you have.

Comment: When you merged, did you merge the texture atlas named `dP` into the trunk?

Comment: Yes, dP.atlas is imported in the project, I haven't commit my project yet because the error occurred.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. I've clean the project, deleted and re added my texture atlases, checked spelling. For some reason, it just can't find them. Will create a new project and try with that. Im thinking there's an Xcode bug in this.

Comment: This worked for me. Go to your project - Build Setting - search Enable Texture Atlas Generation and choose YES. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 18):

Go to you'r Project and follow these steps:-
1> Go to Build Settings,
2> Search for **Enable Texture Atlas Generation** and select YES

Comment: Could be worth mentioning that you actually have to have a folder with the .atlas in your project for that option to be available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by Reseting Contents and Settings of the Simulator

From the top bar:
**iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings...**

I also cleaned the project.